# PyTeX – Python plus TeX

Tags: pdftex, python

What came from to PyTeX – Python plus TeX idea? Could some one provide more information? Some information can be find on this website but as you can see it is outdated at least http://www.pytex.org.
I could not find any direct results of this idea.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Well, the code is available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/pytex/, but it doesn't look like anything's happened there for quite some time.

Comment: I suspect that you've found everything there is to say in public. It looks like the work was led by Jonathan Fine: we could ask him directly, I guess.

Comment: A similar idea is PyLaTeX, which is actively developed (latest release was a few months ago). See for example https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/examples/basic.html.

Comment: And another one is the Python library `latex`, see https://pypi.org/project/latex/.

Comment: Well, in my experience, best you find is PythonTeX. Here on CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/pythontex actively developed, also on GitHub, and the author active here on SE (he was literally helping me today with an issue). What you can do with it? For Example, execute python code and print it into TeX. I am with it taking data from database, making some evaluations, then printing the result to pdf (plots included) and shipping to my boss ...

Comment: Oh sorry, was it more about Python than TeX??

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: The [`sagetex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex) package lets you work with Python, a computer algebra systems called [SAGE](https://www.sagemath.org/), and LaTeX. Open a free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account to get up and running quickly.

Comment: Thank you Werner!

Comment: Dear Tomaš, no it is more about curiosity. To find out is it possible to use TeX dirictly with some language other then Lua and not just Plain TeX.

Comment: There is also Perl and LaTex, via package `perltex`, in terms of languages. And also the `expl3` internal language, if you haven't seen it yet.